# one or more [plural or singular]?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

Should I use singular or plural after `one or more`? 
Example:

> One or more [signal/signals]

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13284/which-is-correct-one-or-more-is-or-one-or-more-are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some variation in the treatment of "One or more" depending on whether the "or more" is understood as "One (or more) signal" or "one or more signals".  In general you the intended meaning is usually the plural and you would be normally be correct to say

> One or more signals are...